# A range with steps bigger than one in freemarker?

Tags: range, sequence, freemarker

### Question

I want to know if you can specify a step size in a numeric range.

For example, exist something like `50..100 in 10` that resolve to `[50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]`?

or if not exist can I make something like `5..10 * 10` and the same result?

---

### Explanation

Here an explanation about my problem (if you like to know more). I have a configuration file with two blocks, the second related with the first.

Something like:

This will configure the application to do first A with parameter 100 and then do B with parameter 200. A will be a easy algorithm than B but less powerfull, but B will also try what A do if it's parameter is lower.

Now I want to launch a test with multiple values to know what is the better combination so I made the next template with freemarker.

```
<#list [50, 100, 200] as A>
<#list [100, 200, 500] as B>

<doA param1="${A}" />
<doB param1="${B}" />

</#list>
</#list>
```

The problem will be the combination of A=200 and B=100, because I already know that B will test A=200 so it is a waste of time to test.

I can solve this with an if, so if A is bigger than B, don't do nothing.

Now the problem have became bigger, and I need to check more values so I want to switch to a range of values, something like:

```
<#list 50..300 as A>
<#list 100..10000 as B>

<#if A < B >

<doA param1="${A}" />
<doB param1="${B}" />

</#if>

</#list>
</#list>
```

But an step of 1 is too small.

Also I think that with this I can do:

```
<#list 50..300 as A>
<#list A..10000 as B>

<doA param1="${A}" />
<doB param1="${B}" />

</#list>
</#list>
```

But I haven't test it. First I need to know that if I can make a big step.

P.D. I have search in freemarker documentation but I don't found nothing about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't specify a step. You can't multiply a whole range at once either. But of course you can do something like `${A*10}` that is similar to having step 10.